# Iterate through a List and add values to 2D Array

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, multidimensional-array

My problem is that I can't figure out how to iterate through my list and assign certain properties to an existing 2D Array.

I have a list which is comprised of 50 courses

```
List<Course> Courses;
```

.. and an array of the same size (sorry I know the logic is poor but these aren't my actual list names, I just need them to be of the same size.

```
object[,] enrolledStudents = new object [50, 2];
```

My understanding is that I will be able to add 50 of each select Course property to this array. Though maybe I need an array of size [50, 50] for this?

Anyway when this was just an array of objects I had no problem looping through the Course list and adding the property I wanted like so

```
    int i = 0;
    foreach (var a in Courses)
    {
        enrolledStudents[i] = a.CourseName;
        i++;
    }
```

This populated my (then 1 dimensional) array with 50 CourseNames, but now I want to be able to add passmark into the array also.

So ideally I want my (now 2 dimensional) array to look like

```
{ y = CourseName, val = PassMark }
{ y = CourseName, val = PassMark }
{ y = CourseName, val = PassMark }
{ y = CourseName, val = PassMark }
...
```

I'll keep googling in the meantime, since this seems like such a basic problem that I should know the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int i = 0;
foreach (var a in Courses)
{
    enrolledStudents[i, 0] = a.CourseName;
    enrolledStudents[i, 1] = a.PassMark;
    i++;
}
```

This should work. You need the array to be 50x2 (50 courses, each has a name and a pass mark), so [50, 2] is the correct one. You can swap the numbers and have [2, 50] as well if you want, depends on your preference. But then note that you need to change [i, 0] to [0, i] as well.

Comment: Thank you for this. Seems so obvious now. Do you know of a way that I can name them y and val respectively for calling them later in my code?

Comment: @bjjrolls Can you elaborate that a bit? I am not sure what you want to name y and val, and in what way do you want to call them later in the code.

Comment: As in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/JVNjs/735/

I want my data to be in that format

Comment: @bjjrolls Not sure you can do anything like that with Arrays. They use indexes only. If you change your approach to something like Dictionaries, then you would have the same structure more or less, as you wouldn't be using indexes to access them, but keys/values, which you could use variable names as "y" and "val" to pass on values to either keys of values.

Answer (score 2):

This is a shorter version of Memfisto's answer:

```
List<Course> Courses = new List<Course>();
string[][] enrolledStudents = new string[50][];
// Create a jagged array so we can change each item like this [i] instead of
// having to go through both indexes like this [x, y].

Courses.Select((a, i) => enrolledStudents[i] = new string[] { a.AccountName, a.PassMark });
```

This uses an overload of Enumerable.Select which allows for the index.

Comment: Thanks, this is elegant, I haven't seen this done so far.

Comment: Are jagged arrays better to use with Select or is that just your preference? Thanks for the shorter version!

Comment: Jagged arrays are better using Select, because their easier to work with. Also you can get an item like this `[int]`, you don't have to have both indexes. While mulidimentional arrays require both indexes `[int, int]`.